# connect vb.net 32 bit with oracle client11g 64 bit on windows10 64 bit operating system

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I have 32 bit visual studio 12, Oracle client 11g 64 bit installed on windows 10 64 bit Operating System.
Is there any way to connect 32 bit visual studio with 64 bit oracle client.

Error Message:: 
Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException.  This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed.

Comment: How did you install 32 bits visual studio on a 64 bits machine.:)

Comment: Nope. Your app and the library you're using must be of the same bitness (Visual Studio's bitness doesn't matter). Change your app to compile as 64-bit (x64).

Comment: @preciousbetine : You can both install and run 32-bit applications on a 64-bit machine. 64-bit Windows comes with a 32-bit emulator/subsystem called WOW64, which allows you to run 32-bit apps on a 64-bit system.

Comment: @VisualVincent wow, i've never used a 64 bit machine before

Comment: @VisualVincent what do you mean by "bitness"..:)

Comment: @preciousbetine : ["Bitness"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bitness) refers to the system's or application's architecture. In this case 32-bit or 64-bit.

Comment: @preciousbetine, you never used a 64 bit machine? We are in 2018!